# I don't understand what does this code line do, $this->link->query($query)?

Tags: php, mysqli

**Only the part which is $this->link->query($query)** I understand that link is the member variable of the class Database but don't understand what is happening when $this->link->query($query) executes? help, I am a novice at coding

*My whole code:*

```
<?php


class Database
{
    public $db_host=DB_HOST;
    public $db_user=DB_USER;
    public $db_pass=DB_PASS;
    public $db_name=DB_NAME;


    public $link;

    public $error;

    public function __construct()

    {



        // Call connect function

        $this->connect();


    }

    private function connect()
    {
        $this->link= new mysqli($this->db_host,$this->db_user,$this->db_pass,$this->db_name);

        if(!$this->link)
        {
            $this->error="Connection Failed";
            return false;
        }

    }

    public function select($query)
    {
        $result=$this->link->query($query) or die ("Query could not execute");
    }

}


?>
```

Comment: I'm not grasping the question here. What's the "problem"? It works or it doesn't? Or, you want to know "how" it all comes together?

Comment: Uh, it runs the query and returns a result?

Comment: problem is that I don't understand how "$this->link->query($query)" is working. I am accessing "$link" member variable using "$this->link" but don't understand what "$this->link->query($query)" is?

Comment: you also realize that these `public $db_host=DB_HOST;
    public $db_user=DB_USER;
    public $db_pass=DB_PASS;
    public $db_name=DB_NAME;` at the end, are all constants. Where are those defined?

Comment: yes, it works. but I want to know how it comes altogether. I was following a course video and intstructor wrote this without explaining much about it.

Comment: Answers Are There For You. *Enjoy*

Comment: It's all in the manual(s) http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: I would say that it is bad form to directly access a property of a class, as it ruins encapsulation....

Comment: and Stack isn't a tutorial site. There's enough out there for you to learn. If nothing is "broke", then there's nothing for us to "fix".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `$this` is the current `Database` object you are using.
2. `->` calls a method or member of that object
3. `link` as you pointed out is a member of `Database` which just happens to be another object of `mysqli`.
4. `query($query)` is a method of link.

So you are calling `mysqli` `query`. Where the param `$query` should be your sql

Comment: Thanks! Thanks a lot! I know Stack Overflow isn't tutorial site but you just cleared a major confusion.

Answer (score 0):

`$this->link` is a database connection object, and it has a method called `query()` for doing database queries and returning a mysqli result object.  The `query()` method takes an SQL string.  So one way to invoke it would be:

```
$result = $this->link->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1") ;
```

It's very common to use a variable instead of a string literal in calls to mysqli `query()`:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1" ;
$result = $this->link->query($sql) ;
```

In the case of your code, the variable containing the SQL string is called `$query`, which can be kind of confusing, especially since `$query` isn't defined anywhere that I can see.